# Facebook game & hardware acceleration

Tags: 18.04, firefox, flash, facebook, hardware-acceleration

I cannot make [Facebook's "Gardenscapes" game](https://apps.facebook.com/gardenscapes) work on my fresh installation with Firefox.
When I start it, it asks me to enable Hardware Acceleration. When the flash popup shows up, "Enable Hardware Acceleration" is already ticked, yet I cannot get past that message. I tried another game and it runs fine but I cannot say i it relies on hardware acceleration or not.

What steps should I take to make this game work? How to check if hardware acceleration works and if not, how to fix it?

**===== Stuff tried/checked =====**

**Ways of installing flash tried:**

- Install `flash plugin` manually
- Install `flashplugin-installer` package
- Install `adobe-flashplugin` and `browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

None of these 3 methods did the trick, I'm currently using the 3rd one.

**OpenGl**

`glxinfo` gives me "OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5"

**Hardware**

- CPU: AMD A6-3400M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics
- GPU:

```
dom@dom-PC:~$ lspci | grep VGA  
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

Trying `lspci -v`, GPU seems to indicate some fault:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)  
    !!! Unknown header type 7f  
    Kernel driver in use: radeon  
   Kernel modules: radeon
```

**Firefox config**

`layers.acceleration.force-enabled` => forced to `true`
`layers.omtp.enabled` => defaults to `true`
`layout.display-list.retain` => defaults to `true`
`layout.display-list.retain` => defaults to `false`, also tried forced to `true`

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Silly to forget that "detail"... I'm using Firefox

Answer (score 0):

It seems you mixed up Adobe Flash hardware acceleration with acceleration with Firefox itself. Thing is that hardware acceleration does NOT work in Flash for Linux from around version 11 which was supposed to be last long term supported. After supported period ended Adobe decided to not drop Flash on linux, and even update it to "current" version but with limited capabilities. Features which was expensive to maintain like hardware Acceleration was disabled completely.

Comment: Indeed, that makes sense thank you. I guess this basically mean I'm doomed?